# Creating glyph index table for PDF text Rendering using Freetype

Tags: pdf, freetype

( PDF Specific ) If we want to render text using freetype, we requires glyph-index corresponding to character..etc. So, do we need to parse a font / embedded-font ( file ) for TrueType, Type1 etc. using tables and data there and then create glyph-index mapping for character? Or there is some shortcut to find glyph-index. More preciously is FT_Get_Char_Index sufficient to give glyph-index in all cases?

Comment: I forgot to mention an important point that I am using PoDoFo for parsing PDF document. Requirement:- CharCode ( from PoDoFo ) to Glyph-Index ( of Freetype ).

Answer (score 1):

Freetype is a rendering engine for several font technologies which are used in PDF.What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I guess he's building a PDF viewer.

Comment: Yeah,I am writing a PDF viewer on top of PoDoFo using cairo and my-final output is a PNG surface w.r.t a PDF page. I had taken care of Graphics state implementation and other transformations. I tested and figured out that mapping to correct glyph-index is the major portion of work. Just wanted to know whether I have to parse the font file and create this glyphTable from scracth or freetype can help me on this. For example to make a glyph-index table for TrueType font, shall I parse the font ( embedded ) read its charmap, glyf, post table..etc and then using them to create glyph-index table.

Comment: You may be able to use the font data as is or may need to restructure. It depends on how the fonts are structured and which font technology you are using

Comment: Thank u for replying. It seems it's not a question which can be answered in few lines. I have to dig deeper in font-format basics.